# Converting a particular key into Array of object instead of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xml2js

I have a service which returns XML resposne. I am using xml2JS to parse the XML to JSON. The XML looks like -

```
<root>
  <children>
    <type>custom</type>
    <optional>false</optional>
    <level>1</level>
    <id>55705</id>
    <title>Reference Resources</title>
    <role>admin</role>
    <children>
      <mediano>1</mediano>
      <id>be0_1436</id>
      <title>Tests</title>
      <level>2</level>
      <optional>false</optional>
      <role>admin</role>
      <type>custom</type>
      <children>
        <mediano>2</mediano>
        <id>be1_1401</id>
        <title>Word Documents</title>
        <level>3</level>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <role>admin</role>
        <type>custom</type>
        <children>
          <mediano>3</mediano>
          <id>be2_1389</id>
          <title>Progress Tests Units 1-2A</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>admin</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>4</mediano>
          <id>be3_1395</id>
          <title>Progress Tests Units 1-2B</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>admin</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>5</mediano>
          <id>be4_1387</id>
          <title>Progress Tests Units 3-4A</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>admin</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>6</mediano>
          <id>be5_1382</id>
          <title>Progress Tests Units 3-4B</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>admin</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
      </children>
      <children>
        <mediano>7</mediano>
        <id>be6_1374</id>
        <title>Audios</title>
        <level>3</level>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <role>admin</role>
        <type>custom</type>
        <children>
          <mediano>8</mediano>
          <id>be7_1354</id>
          <title>Track 1</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>admin</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>9</mediano>
          <id>be8_1346</id>
          <title>Track 2</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>admin</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>10</mediano>
          <id>be9_1328</id>
          <title>Track 3</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>admin</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>11</mediano>
          <id>be10_1326</id>
          <title>Track 4</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>admin</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>12</mediano>
          <id>be11_1315</id>
          <title>Tests Audio Scripts</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>admin</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
      </children>
    </children>
    <children>
      <mediano>13</mediano>
      <id>be12_1305</id>
      <title>Answer Key</title>
      <level>2</level>
      <optional>false</optional>
      <role>admin</role>
      <type>public</type>
    </children>
    <children>
      <mediano>14</mediano>
      <id>e0adb276a4c91bd4e040140ad4036164</id>
      <title>Stopwatch</title>
      <level>2</level>
      <optional>false</optional>
      <role>admin</role>
      <type>public</type>
    </children>
    <children>
      <mediano>15</mediano>
      <id>e253b516eaa57b95e040140ad5035634</id>
      <title>Scoreboard</title>
      <level>2</level>
      <optional>false</optional>
      <role>admin</role>
      <type>public</type>
    </children>
  </children>
  <children>
    <type>custom</type>
    <optional>false</optional>
    <level>1</level>
    <id>55706</id>
    <title>title shots</title>
    <role>all</role>
    <children>
      <mediano>1</mediano>
      <id>ecb70c0e55965669e040140ad5033e0b</id>
      <title>title shots</title>
      <level>2</level>
      <optional>false</optional>
      <role>all</role>
      <type>public</type>
    </children>
    <children>
      <mediano>2</mediano>
      <id>191bd859902e7801e0532502140a370c</id>
      <title>html url public</title>
      <level>2</level>
      <optional>false</optional>
      <role>all</role>
      <type>public</type>
    </children>
  </children>
  <children>
    <type>custom</type>
    <optional>false</optional>
    <level>1</level>
    <id>55707</id>
    <title>Media and Games</title>
    <role>all</role>
    <children>
      <mediano>1</mediano>
      <id>be13_1299</id>
      <title>Podcasts and Worksheets</title>
      <level>2</level>
      <optional>false</optional>
      <role>all</role>
      <type>custom</type>
      <children>
        <mediano>2</mediano>
        <id>be14_1290</id>
        <title>Unit 1</title>
        <level>3</level>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <role>all</role>
        <type>custom</type>
        <children>
          <mediano>3</mediano>
          <id>be15_1280</id>
          <title>Podcast</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>all</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>4</mediano>
          <id>be16_1272</id>
          <title>Worksheet</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>all</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>5</mediano>
          <id>be17_1266</id>
          <title>Script</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>admin</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
      </children>
      <children>
        <mediano>6</mediano>
        <id>be18_1250</id>
        <title>Unit 2</title>
        <level>3</level>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <role>all</role>
        <type>custom</type>
        <children>
          <mediano>7</mediano>
          <id>be19_1240</id>
          <title>Podcast</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>all</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>8</mediano>
          <id>be20_1231</id>
          <title>Worksheet</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>all</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>9</mediano>
          <id>be21_1216</id>
          <title>Script</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>admin</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
      </children>
      <children>
        <mediano>10</mediano>
        <id>be22_1189</id>
        <title>Unit 3</title>
        <level>3</level>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <role>all</role>
        <type>custom</type>
        <children>
          <mediano>11</mediano>
          <id>be23_1131</id>
          <title>Podcast</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>all</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>12</mediano>
          <id>be24_1052</id>
          <title>Worksheet</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>all</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>13</mediano>
          <id>be25_896</id>
          <title>Script</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>admin</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
      </children>
    </children>
    <children>
      <mediano>14</mediano>
      <id>be26_801</id>
      <title>Audio Bank</title>
      <level>2</level>
      <optional>false</optional>
      <role>all</role>
      <type>custom</type>
      <children>
        <mediano>15</mediano>
        <id>be27_786</id>
        <title>Unit 1</title>
        <level>3</level>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <role>all</role>
        <type>custom</type>
        <children>
          <mediano>16</mediano>
          <id>be28_777</id>
          <title>Recording 1</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>all</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>17</mediano>
          <id>be29_769</id>
          <title>Recording 2</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>all</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>18</mediano>
          <id>be30_767</id>
          <title>Recording 3</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>all</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>19</mediano>
          <id>be31_756</id>
          <title>Recording 4</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>all</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>20</mediano>
          <id>be32_750</id>
          <title>Recording 5</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>all</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>21</mediano>
          <id>be33_746</id>
          <title>Recording 6</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>all</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
        <children>
          <mediano>22</mediano>
          <id>be34_740</id>
          <title>Recording 7</title>
          <level>4</level>
          <optional>false</optional>
          <role>all</role>
          <type>public</type>
        </children>
      </children>
    </children>
    <children>
      <mediano>23</mediano>
      <id>be35_731</id>
      <title>Games</title>
      <level>2</level>
      <optional>false</optional>
      <role>all</role>
      <type>custom</type>
      <children>
        <mediano>24</mediano>
        <id>be36_720</id>
        <title>Pelmanism</title>
        <level>3</level>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <role>all</role>
        <type>public</type>
      </children>
      <children>
        <mediano>25</mediano>
        <id>be37_718</id>
        <title>Hangman</title>
        <level>3</level>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <role>all</role>
        <type>public</type>
      </children>
      <children>
        <mediano>26</mediano>
        <id>be38_712</id>
        <title>Doorbuster</title>
        <level>3</level>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <role>all</role>
        <type>public</type>
      </children>
    </children>
    <children>
      <mediano>27</mediano>
      <id>13bef4738dd56268e0532402140ab184</id>
      <title>Smart secret Player</title>
      <level>2</level>
      <optional>false</optional>
      <role>all</role>
      <type>custom</type>
      <children>
        <mediano>28</mediano>
        <id>13bef4738dd66268e0532402140ab184</id>
        <title>pss_1</title>
        <level>3</level>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <role>all</role>
        <type>public</type>
      </children>
      <children>
        <mediano>29</mediano>
        <id>13bef4738dd86268e0532402140ab184</id>
        <title>pss_2</title>
        <level>3</level>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <role>all</role>
        <type>public</type>
      </children>
    </children>
  </children>
  </children>
</root>
```

After parsing the JSON looks like -

```
[
  {
    "type": "custom",
    "optional": "false",
    "level": "1",
    "id": "55705",
    "title": "Reference Resources",
    "role": "admin",
    "children": [
      {
        "mediano": "1",
        "id": "be0_1436",
        "title": "Tests",
        "level": "2",
        "optional": "false",
        "role": "admin",
        "type": "custom",
        "children": [
          {
            "mediano": "2",
            "id": "be1_1401",
            "title": "Word Documents",
            "level": "3",
            "optional": "false",
            "role": "admin",
            "type": "custom",
            "children": [
              {
                "mediano": "3",
                "id": "be2_1389",
                "title": "Progress Tests Units 1-2A",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "admin",
                "type": "public"
              },
              {
                "mediano": "4",
                "id": "be3_1395",
                "title": "Progress Tests Units 1-2B",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "admin",
                "type": "public"
              },
              {
                "mediano": "5",
                "id": "be4_1387",
                "title": "Progress Tests Units 3-4A",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "admin",
                "type": "public"
              },
              {
                "mediano": "6",
                "id": "be5_1382",
                "title": "Progress Tests Units 3-4B",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "admin",
                "type": "public"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "mediano": "7",
            "id": "be6_1374",
            "title": "Audios",
            "level": "3",
            "optional": "false",
            "role": "admin",
            "type": "custom",
            "children": [
              {
                "mediano": "8",
                "id": "be7_1354",
                "title": "Track 1",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "admin",
                "type": "public"
              },
              {
                "mediano": "9",
                "id": "be8_1346",
                "title": "Track 2",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "admin",
                "type": "public"
              },
              {
                "mediano": "10",
                "id": "be9_1328",
                "title": "Track 3",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "admin",
                "type": "public"
              },
              {
                "mediano": "11",
                "id": "be10_1326",
                "title": "Track 4",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "admin",
                "type": "public"
              },
              {
                "mediano": "12",
                "id": "be11_1315",
                "title": "Tests Audio Scripts",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "admin",
                "type": "public"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "mediano": "13",
        "id": "be12_1305",
        "title": "Answer Key",
        "level": "2",
        "optional": "false",
        "role": "admin",
        "type": "public"
      },
      {
        "mediano": "14",
        "id": "e0adb276a4c91bd4e040140ad4036164",
        "title": "Stopwatch",
        "level": "2",
        "optional": "false",
        "role": "admin",
        "type": "public"
      },
      {
        "mediano": "15",
        "id": "e253b516eaa57b95e040140ad5035634",
        "title": "Scoreboard",
        "level": "2",
        "optional": "false",
        "role": "admin",
        "type": "public"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "custom",
    "optional": "false",
    "level": "1",
    "id": "55706",
    "title": "title shots",
    "role": "all",
    "children": [
      {
        "mediano": "1",
        "id": "ecb70c0e55965669e040140ad5033e0b",
        "title": "title shots",
        "level": "2",
        "optional": "false",
        "role": "all",
        "type": "public"
      },
      {
        "mediano": "2",
        "id": "191bd859902e7801e0532502140a370c",
        "title": "html url public",
        "level": "2",
        "optional": "false",
        "role": "all",
        "type": "public"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "custom",
    "optional": "false",
    "level": "1",
    "id": "55707",
    "title": "Media and Games",
    "role": "all",
    "children": [
      {
        "mediano": "1",
        "id": "be13_1299",
        "title": "Podcasts and Worksheets",
        "level": "2",
        "optional": "false",
        "role": "all",
        "type": "custom",
        "children": [
          {
            "mediano": "2",
            "id": "be14_1290",
            "title": "Unit 1",
            "level": "3",
            "optional": "false",
            "role": "all",
            "type": "custom",
            "children": [
              {
                "mediano": "3",
                "id": "be15_1280",
                "title": "Podcast",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "all",
                "type": "public"
              },
              {
                "mediano": "4",
                "id": "be16_1272",
                "title": "Worksheet",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "all",
                "type": "public"
              },
              {
                "mediano": "5",
                "id": "be17_1266",
                "title": "Script",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "admin",
                "type": "public"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "mediano": "6",
            "id": "be18_1250",
            "title": "Unit 2",
            "level": "3",
            "optional": "false",
            "role": "all",
            "type": "custom",
            "children": [
              {
                "mediano": "7",
                "id": "be19_1240",
                "title": "Podcast",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "all",
                "type": "public"
              },
              {
                "mediano": "8",
                "id": "be20_1231",
                "title": "Worksheet",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "all",
                "type": "public"
              },
              {
                "mediano": "9",
                "id": "be21_1216",
                "title": "Script",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "admin",
                "type": "public"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "mediano": "10",
            "id": "be22_1189",
            "title": "Unit 3",
            "level": "3",
            "optional": "false",
            "role": "all",
            "type": "custom",
            "children": [
              {
                "mediano": "11",
                "id": "be23_1131",
                "title": "Podcast",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "all",
                "type": "public"
              },
              {
                "mediano": "12",
                "id": "be24_1052",
                "title": "Worksheet",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "all",
                "type": "public"
              },
              {
                "mediano": "13",
                "id": "be25_896",
                "title": "Script",
                "level": "4",
                "optional": "false",
                "role": "admin",
                "type": "public"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "mediano": "14",
        "id": "be26_801",
        "title": "Audio Bank",
        "level": "2",
        "optional": "false",
        "role": "all",
        "type": "custom",
        "children": {
          "mediano": "15",
          "id": "be27_786",
          "title": "Unit 1",
          "level": "3",
          "optional": "false",
          "role": "all",
          "type": "custom",
          "children": [
            {
              "mediano": "16",
              "id": "be28_777",
              "title": "Recording 1",
              "level": "4",
              "optional": "false",
              "role": "all",
              "type": "public"
            },
            {
              "mediano": "17",
              "id": "be29_769",
              "title": "Recording 2",
              "level": "4",
              "optional": "false",
              "role": "all",
              "type": "public"
            },
            {
              "mediano": "18",
              "id": "be30_767",
              "title": "Recording 3",
              "level": "4",
              "optional": "false",
              "role": "all",
              "type": "public"
            },
            {
              "mediano": "19",
              "id": "be31_756",
              "title": "Recording 4",
              "level": "4",
              "optional": "false",
              "role": "all",
              "type": "public"
            },
            {
              "mediano": "20",
              "id": "be32_750",
              "title": "Recording 5",
              "level": "4",
              "optional": "false",
              "role": "all",
              "type": "public"
            },
            {
              "mediano": "21",
              "id": "be33_746",
              "title": "Recording 6",
              "level": "4",
              "optional": "false",
              "role": "all",
              "type": "public"
            },
            {
              "mediano": "22",
              "id": "be34_740",
              "title": "Recording 7",
              "level": "4",
              "optional": "false",
              "role": "all",
              "type": "public"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "mediano": "23",
        "id": "be35_731",
        "title": "Games",
        "level": "2",
        "optional": "false",
        "role": "all",
        "type": "custom",
        "children": [
          {
            "mediano": "24",
            "id": "be36_720",
            "title": "Pelmanism",
            "level": "3",
            "optional": "false",
            "role": "all",
            "type": "public"
          },
          {
            "mediano": "25",
            "id": "be37_718",
            "title": "Hangman",
            "level": "3",
            "optional": "false",
            "role": "all",
            "type": "public"
          },
          {
            "mediano": "26",
            "id": "be38_712",
            "title": "Doorbuster",
            "level": "3",
            "optional": "false",
            "role": "all",
            "type": "public"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "mediano": "27",
        "id": "13bef4738dd56268e0532402140ab184",
        "title": "Smart secret Player",
        "level": "2",
        "optional": "false",
        "role": "all",
        "type": "custom",
        "children": [
          {
            "mediano": "28",
            "id": "13bef4738dd66268e0532402140ab184",
            "title": "pss_1",
            "level": "3",
            "optional": "false",
            "role": "all",
            "type": "public"
          },
          {
            "mediano": "29",
            "id": "13bef4738dd86268e0532402140ab184",
            "title": "pss_2",
            "level": "3",
            "optional": "false",
            "role": "all",
            "type": "public"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The key 'children' can have one record or multiple records. When the key 'children' has one record, the parser makes the type as object and when there are multiple records, it becomes an array, which as I understand is the way in which xml2JS parser works. Per my requirement, I want this key to be an array irrespective of the number of records it has. Also, this is an array, which can be nested to n-th level and the key 'children' should be an array of objects, always. Search for **"children": {**. I want this to be **"children": [**

This is a sample response. There can be multiple similar instances. Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Can you please add the raw XML before the parse?

Comment: Maybe parse the XML "by hand" using the relevant XML APIs instead of using XML2JS or some other library that needs to do guesswork like this.